# How to convert Json string to object in rxjs angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have two component one is lead board and other is lead card i am using drag and drop of angular material to generate board and i have generated board list using below code and i generate card of darg and drop using ngFor="let lead of leadGroup.group" i want to conver LeadStatusTitle in object so that i can display it on html page . I am not getting data for LeadStatusTitle

**lead-board-Component.html**

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="drag-container" *ngFor="let leadGroup of leadKeyValue$ | async">
    <h4>{{ leadGroup.LeadStatusTitle }}</h4>
    <div
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="leadGroup.group"
      class="item-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
    >
      <div class="item-box" *ngFor="let lead of leadGroup.group" cdkDrag>
        <app-lead-card lead></app-lead-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**lead-card.Component.html**

```
<div>{{ lead.Company }}</div>
```

**lead-board.Component.ts**

```
leadKeyValue$: Observable<
    {
      LeadStatusTitle: string;
      group: string[];
    }[]
  >;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.leads$ = this.store.select(getLeads);
    // this.store.dispatch(LeadActions.loadLeads());
    this.leads$.subscribe((x) => {
      this.leadKeyValue$ = from(x).pipe(
        groupBy((lead) => lead.LeadStatus),
        mergeMap((obs) => {
          console.log(obs);
          return obs.pipe(
            map((x) => JSON.stringify(x)),
            toArray(),
            map((items) => {
              return {
                LeadStatusTitle: obs.key,
                group: items,
              };
            })
          );
        }),
        toArray()
      );
    });
  }
```

When i binding {{ lead.Company }} in  **lead-card.Component.ts** i am getting error TS2339: Property 'Company' does not exist on type 'string'.
Thank you

Comment: Could you please add more details, what are you trying to do? And what have you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: I am trying to bind this group by data to drag and drop in angular material so want to conver above json string into object so that i can bind it to ngFor

Comment: Could you please update the question to include the expected result that should be passed to the ngFor?

Comment: Added some more code ....i just want to convert it into object i am using json.parser(x)

Comment: Where do you need to use the `FirstName` exactly, please?

Comment: You don't need to convert a JSON to object, since it is already considered an object if it is a valid JSON, you just need to cast it with an interface and you are good to go!

Comment: You should change the question title to something more specific!

Comment: I am not getting LeadStatusTitle so i have to convret it

Comment: Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not bound the input correctly:

```html
<div class="item-box" *ngFor="let lead of leadGroup.group" cdkDrag>
    <app-lead-card lead></app-lead-card>
</div>
```

should look more like:

```html
<div class="item-box" *ngFor="let lead of leadGroup.group" cdkDrag>
    <app-lead-card lead="lead"></app-lead-card>
</div>
```

You need to specify an `@Input()` attribute in your `lead-card.Component.ts` but you didn't post the code for that so I cannot check it.

I suggest you read the angular guide for this: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: As I have use json.stringify I need to convert it in object ,now i am getting data in **lead-carde.component.html** but i am not getting LeadStatusTitile so i need to convert it first please tell me how should i do this

Comment: Please help me with this